# What is the URL_CHANGED Event on IIS7 Request Tracing Log?

Tags: iis, php, rewrite, logging, trace

I just enabled [Failed Request Tracing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/467/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules/) for a site and I get a URL_CHANGED event as the third item on the log.

```
1. GENERAL_REQUEST_START SiteId="1", AppPoolId="DefaultAppPool", ConnId="1610613013", RawConnId="0", RequestURL="http://example.com:80/test/wp-admin/", RequestVerb="GET" 15:35:54.176 
2. GENERAL_SET_REQUEST_HEADER HeaderName="AspFilterSessionId", HeaderValue="", Replace="true" 15:35:54.192 
3. URL_CHANGED OldUrl="/test/wp-admin/", NewUrl="/index.php/test/wp-admin/" 15:35:54.192
4. GENERAL_REQUEST_HEADERS [...]
5. GENERAL_GET_URL_METADATA [...]
6. URL_REWRITE_START [...]
```

Can someone tell me where the **URL_CHANGED** event comes from and how I can prevent it?

Update:
The "default document" is set to "index.php" on our server. Could it be that the server automatically appends index.php to a path if the path does not specify a proper file or folder? I tried removing all "default document" entries but this didn't change the behavior...

Update2:
I am still looking for an answer to this question... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The URL_CHANGED message is usually an indicator that a URL re-write rule is being applied. You need to look at how you URL re-writing is configured in IIS to see why that is happening.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but the url rewrite rules don't kick in till event #6...